# Convert string in T-SQL (YYYMMDD)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime-conversion

I have a column exit_date with varchar like `5/21/2008 0:00` and I need to update it to a string like `YYYYMMDD`, any way to do that?

```
5/21/2008 0:00  ==> 20080521  
1/1/2007 0:00   ==> 20070101
```

How to do something like

```
select convert('5/21/2008 0:00', 'YYYYMMDD').
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CONVERT allows a style for conversions datetime/varchar in both directions. Saying that, you have a format that is not listed. And you actually have 2 conversions too: you need to get it into datetime first

In my local SQL install that has the default "us_english" settings, this works out of the box

```
select convert(datetime, '5/21/2008 0:00')
```

thus

```
select convert(char(8), convert(datetime, '5/21/2008 0:00'), 112)
```

You can use SET LANGUAGE to modify to us_english temporarily

Comment: +1. I must have missed your answer somehow, otherwise I wouldn't have posted mine. (I had probably kept the page open for too long before answering.) Anyway, good point about the language setting. Should have remembered that too.

Answer (score 2):

Head over to http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: nice link.. gr8 one... would be better if it included the answer too.. SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS [YYYYMMDD]

Comment: @gidion, thanks for the link ;)  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS [YYYYMMDD] is what the OP needs ;)

Comment: @KoolKabin, LOL... With such a giant list of options guessed the answer would be in there. If not, hoped the question asker would be able to infer the answer from the info.

Comment: But that's doesn't resolve my problem, how to use select convert('5/21/2008 0:00' XXXXX), to get YYYYMMDD?

Comment: The answer is: don't use it that way, it's the wrong syntax. `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(DATETIME, '5/21/2008 0:00'), 112)` is what you should use for your particular example.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see first that it was a **varchar column** that needed the conversion.

So, as I said in my comment to Gidon's answer, basically you should probably go like this: `CONVERT(varchar(8), CAST(your_varchar_date AS datetime), 112)`.

If you are converting the values in-place, then here's a fuller example of how to apply it:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET exit_date = CONVERT(varchar(8), CONVERT(datetime, exit_date), 112)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a function on my blog to support date conversions in T-SQL using .Net style format masks. Not trying to plug my blog or anything it's just where I post my code snippets.

Using my function `SELECT dbo.fnc_FormatDate(getdate(), 'YYYYMMDD')` will do what you want.

http://bitmugger.blogspot.com/2011/07/convert-t-sql-datetime-to-strings-using.html